# glide not loading image from sdcard

Tags: java, android

I want to put an image that is in my sdcard but it doesn't show up, i thought there is a problem with the library of glide or a permission, i'm stacked in there for 2 days please help me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final static String PATH_SD_CARD = "/Images/Mj.jpg";
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != getPackageManager().PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // Explain to the user why we need to read the contacts
            }

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is an
            // app-defined int constant that should be quite unique

            return;
        }

        ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+PATH_SD_CARD)
                .into(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: is "Images" folder is present in sdcard or it is inside some other folder ?

Comment: Debugging always works and a best friend of developer!

Comment: print Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+PATH_SD_CARD and check in device root/children path are correct or not

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Test this code :

```
String fileName = "myImage.jpg";
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName;

        File file = new File(imagePath);
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(imageUri)
                        .into(imgView);
```

Comment: i was forced to put the image in in the internal storage like said Gotiasits and used the script given by Spp93  it worked, many thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

have you added permission in android manifest file like below code..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: i did it and nothing

Comment: check glide in take any path in load call.

Comment: Have you checked for runtime permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` doesn't guarantee extеrnal storage in the way of SDcard, but word *external* is in reference to "external to the Application". This path will in most cases give you: `/storage/emulated/0/`.

Since path to the any "drive" that isn't integral part of the device can have different names, you need some other way to find it, regardless of the device. IMO, the most efficient and secure way is querying the `MediaStore` with some criteria.

Quick solution could be to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` witch gives you `Files[]` where your App hat "its" directories. Second element to this array is path on the SDCard. If you go two "levels" up from there (`.getParentFile()`), you'll get a reference to your "root" SDCard directory.

And off course, as already mentioned, do use debugging extensively to get an idea where it went wrong.